# How do I add contents of a file to a 2D array in assembly language

Tags: assembly, multidimensional-array, io, irvine32

I would like to add the contents of this text file to a 2D array in assembly language (Irvine Libraries).

The text file contains:

```
D,84,2
A,90,3
A,87,4
B,35,4
B,100,1
C,75,1
D,84,1
B,87,2
A,0,2
C,25,2
D,45,3
E,35,3
A,90,1
B,100,3
C,75,3
E,35,1
C,78,4
E,35,2
D,100,4
E,0,4
```

The letter A to E represents the columns and the numbers 1 to 4 represents the rows. The values in between are the data that goes in the 2D array. I have been able to read from the text and display the values but I'm having a hard time adding these to an array.
The professor recommended we use this method but it is not working for me:

```
; Insert score at reviews[rowIndex][colIndex]
    mov      edx,rowSize           ; row size in bytes
    mov      eax,rowIndex          ; row index
    mul      edx                   ; row index * row size
    mov      index,eax             ; save row index * row size
    mov      eax,colIndex          ; load col index
    shl      eax,2                 ; eax = colIndex * 4
    add      eax,index             ; eax contains offset
    mov      edx,score             ; edx = reviewer's score
    mov      ebx,OFFSET reviews    ; array of review scores
    mov      [ebx + eax],edx       ; Store score for movie
```

What I have done so far:

```
;Include Package
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc
BUFFER_SIZE = 5000

;Data section declare variable
.data
buffer BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)
filename BYTE 80 DUP(0)
fileHandle HANDLE ?

.code                    ;Define the code section
main PROC
; Let user input a filename.
    mWrite "Enter an input filename: "
    mov  edx,OFFSET filename
    mov  ecx,SIZEOF filename
    call ReadString
; Open the file for input.
    mov  edx,OFFSET filename
    call OpenInputFile
    mov  fileHandle,eax
; Check for errors.
    cmp  eax,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE   ; error opening file?
    jne  file_ok                    ; no: skip
    mWrite <"Cannot open file",0dh,0ah>
    jmp  quit                       ; and quit
file_ok:
; Read the file into a buffer.
    mov  edx,OFFSET buffer
    mov  ecx,BUFFER_SIZE
    call ReadFromFile
    jnc  check_buffer_size          ; error reading?
    mWrite "Error reading file. "   ; yes: show error message
    call WriteWindowsMsg
    jmp  close_file
check_buffer_size:
    cmp  eax,BUFFER_SIZE            ; buffer large enough?
    jb   buf_size_ok                ; yes
    mWrite <"Error: Buffer too small for the file",0dh,0ah>
    jmp  quit                       ; and quit
buf_size_ok:
    mov  buffer[eax],0              ; insert null terminator
    mWrite "File size: "
    call WriteDec                   ; display file size
    call Crlf
; Display the buffer.
    mWrite <"Buffer:",0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah<
    mov  edx,OFFSET buffer          ; display the buffer
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
close_file:
    mov  eax,fileHandle
    call CloseFile
quit:

    ; Insert score at reviews[rowIndex][colIndex]
    mov      edx,rowSize           ; row size in bytes
    mov      eax,rowIndex          ; row index
    mul      edx                   ; row index * row size
    mov      index,eax             ; save row index * row size
    mov      eax,colIndex          ; load col index
    shl      eax,2                 ; eax = colIndex * 4
    add      eax,index             ; eax contains offset
    mov      edx,score             ; edx = reviewer's score
    mov      ebx,OFFSET reviews    ; array of review scores
    mov      [ebx + eax],edx       ; Store score for movie


;End the procedure
main ENDP

;End the main function
END main
```

[image]
Kindly assist.

Comment: Your professor's code is correct (despite some apparent inefficiencies). What did you do and what exactly when wrong?

Comment: I was able to read from the file and display the contents of the file. But I tried using this method to load them to the array but it would not.

Comment: It's better to show what you actually did. The code you showed here should work when used correctly.

Comment: I am editing the post to add the code

Comment: Just did @xiver77. Please assist me. I have been at this for over 2 weeks and have not been too successful.

Comment: Where is `rowIndex`, `colIndex`, `rowSize`, etc? You've referenced the symbol, but I see nowhere they're defined. Also please show us the error message.

Comment: I added the error message and attempted to define variables

Comment: The error clearly says `undefined symbol`, please define a symbol, and you can copy the messages on the console screen instead of capturing.

Comment: Looks like `rowSize` and so on could just be placeholders for other registers (or constants for the size).  Your professor maybe didn't intend you to actually create labels and static storage for all of those names.  That would explain why they didn't include a `.data` section with `rowIndex: dd 0` and so on.